# Shoud I unsubscribe from observable in case?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have method that is called from template:

```
public submit(): void {
    const data = { ...this.parcel, ...this.form.value, appid: this.appid };
    const requestEgrnData = {};

    iif(
        () => this.mode === MODES.CREATE,
        this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository
            .create(data)
            .pipe(switchMap(() => (this.cadnum.value ? this.egrnService.SendRequestGetEGRP(requestEgrnData) : of(null)))),
        this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository.update(data),
    )
        .pipe(indicate(this.loading$), observableHandlerResponse(this.messageService))
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.dialogRef.close(true);
        });
}
```

Should I unsubscribe from `this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository` and from outer `this.egrnService.SendRequestGetEGRP`, `this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository.update`?

Or enough unsubscribe from `let subscription = this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository()...`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from \`Subscription\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Comment: @fridoo The referenced question covers only basic observables and their subscriptions. This question is asking about inner Observables and their subscriptions. So no, this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: When I dont need to unsubscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the entire subscription is
`const subscription = iif(...) .subscribe(() => { this.dialogRef.close(true);});`

so this `subscription` can be unsubscribed.

Answer (score 2):

you should and only can unsubscribe only in places where you've called `subscribe()` (or in rare cases `connect()`) explicitly. the dependant "subscriptions" if any, will be auto unsubscribed when you unsubscribe from the main one

Comment: In my case it is only  `let subscription = this.applicationOrderParcelsRepository()`. `subscription.unsubscribe()`

Comment: no. In your case it should be `let subscription = iif(.....).pipe().subscribe(...)` <--- see, here subscribe is explicitly called. this.`.subscribe()` call returns a `Subscription`. if you then `subscription.unsubscribe()`, all the logic in this code will stop

Comment: Also form I need unsubscrive from `fromEvent(this.inputHouseSearch.nativeElement, 'keyup').subscribe()`. What if there are some subscription on the page? How to unsubscribe all in destructor?

Comment: there are several ways, but there is no elegant easy way to do it. you either save them and unsubscribe, or use the tricks that do almost the same